# Is instantly occupy the correct word (head, body)?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> The decapitated head of a dead man instantly occupied the body of the headless
> hunter as it galloped through the field on his headless horse.

The head appeared instantly out of thin air, so do you say occupied, or do you say swapped? I am not sure if you can just say instantly occupied. The head is now attached to the body. You can't use swapped, because the body was headless. Is there a better way to express this?

Comment: _Occupy_ usually implies being in something, not on it.

Comment: Please don't say "decapitated head", it doesn't make any sense (at least unless the head used to have a head of its own and then lost it, which really isn't likely to be the case). Try "the severed head of a dead man" or "the head of a decapitated man" instead. Or "the severed head of a decapitated man".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"appeared" maybe a better choice. Try this I have rearranged things a little.

The head of **a/the** decapitated man instantly appeared on the body of the headless hunter as **he** galloped through the field on his headless horse.

I do not know if it is specific or non specified "headless man" hence a/the